# Augmented Reality with Unity ARFoundation on mobile device front-facing camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

Does anyone know if the Unity library ARFoundation works with the front-facing camera on a mobile device? I am having trouble finding recent answers online

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the **AR Camera -> AR Camera Manager** and change the [CameraFacingDirection](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.arfoundation@4.0/api/UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation.CameraFacingDirection.html) to User.
Now the mobile will use the Front camera if the feature works with front camera. If not, it will enable the back camera.

[image: User direction]

Disclosure: Lot's of features like *Image 2D Tracking* and *Body Tracking* can't work with front camera :(